# Interview: Know everything shallowly OR Know completely what you have dealt with

Tags: interviewing

When preparing for an interview, what should be the best strategy ?

> 1. To know basic concepts (primitive aspects of a language) and other topics shallowly

So as one can show that his basics are really strong and he knows what other topic means or how the other topics can later be worked on.

Or

> 2. To know everything about something but nothing about other things?

So that one can show that whatever concept he knows he knows it thoroughly, but he doesn't have an idea of rest of the topics.

Comment: This will depend on the role you are applying for, your previous experience and what the interview panel are looking for.  It's going to be _very_ opinion based.  Voting to close!

Comment: Yes exactly, opinions are required so as why we post questions. The question can be answered with 3 categories in mind viz. Entry Level, Intermediate and Advanced.

Comment: Opinions are fine, but what you are looking for is a _consensus_ of what constitutes good preparation for an interview.  This will be different for every situation and as such is too broad to give a definitive answer.  Your categorisation doesn't include industry sector, the level of technical or business expertise, duration of the role (permanent vs contract) among a thousand other dimensions.  There are so many possible permutations that it becomes impossible to produce a "right" answer in this Q&A format.

Comment: I would suggest that you be able to answer basic questions on every technology that you mnention in your resume. You should have at least one that you can answer more detailed questions on for every job that is not entry level and that shoudl correspond to the technology(IES0 that you have clearly used more often based on your descriptions of what you have done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly it depends on interviewer that what he/she thinks and what role they want. But you should be ready with basic concepts and current technologies/updates in your profile. For ex: if you are going to attend interview for PHP developer then it is require to be strong in basic PHP and OOPs concepts.

After basic concepts it comes to what they want you to do. For ex: If they want candidate who can work with CMS then they will start to ask in depth about that CMS. Before interview it would be better thta better you collect more detail about company domain and projects they do so you can do interview preparation in that way.